# C while loop extra iteration

Tags: c, while-loop, iteration

I'm attempting input verification of the scanf function. I've already fixed the input to ignore blank space (" %c....").

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  char c1, c2, c3;
  int k, done = 0;
  float x;
  double y;

  do {
    printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", "Input the following: three characters,", " an int,", " a float,", " and a double: \n");
    if(scanf(" %c%c%c%d%f%lf", &c1, &c2, &c3, &k, &x, &y) == 6){
      printf("\nHere is the data that you typed in: \n");
      printf("%3c%3c%3c%5d%17e%17e\n\n", c1, c2, c3, k, x, y);
      done = 1;
    } else {
      printf("Invalid input!");
    }
  } while (done != 0);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by extra iteration?

Comment: You can also use a `while (true) { .. break; }` construct to avoid a 'stop variable' in some cases, such as this.

Comment: Or use a do...while loop if you need an iteration at least once.

Comment: When asking "what's wrong" you should say why you think there is something wrong; including error/warning messages (if any), and if the program runs; then the input you gave it, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Apologies everyone for not explaining further (I added an explanation down the bottom when I was asking the question, but for some reason it got removed). The intention of the code was to loop through until the correct input was supplied. However, even when I gave it the right input, the results would display and the program would loop back through again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all variable `done` was not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
int k, done;
//...
while(done != 1){
```

You must initialize it for example like

```
int k, done = 0;
```

But it would be better to write a more suitable loop. That is instead of the while loop it is better to use do-while loop. For example

```
int done = 0;
//...

do
{
    printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", "Input the following: three characters,", " an int,", " a float,", " and a double: \n");
    if(scanf(" %c%c%c%d%f%lf", &c1, &c2, &c3, &k, &x, &y) == 6){
      printf("\nHere is the data that you typed in: \n");
      printf("%3c%3c%3c%5d%17e%17e\n\n", c1, c2, c3, k, x, y);
      done = 1;
    } else {
      printf("Invalid input!");
    }
} while ( done != 1 );
```

Secondly in the scanf call you should specify balnks for format specifiers `%c`

For example

```
    if(scanf(" %c %c %c%d%f%lf", &c1, &c2, &c3, &k, &x, &y) == 6){
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I decided to take your advice and use a Do-While loop. (as for the %c fix, I had done that on recommendation from other answers I could find one the web.)

However, this doesn't fix the underlying issue of the loop executing an additional time.

Is it possible that my if statement for verification is wrong? (once I've put the correct value types in, it outputs and then loops back into the function again)

Comment: @Ashley Rowland  The condition in the do-while loop should be while (done != 1). ;

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your variables. At least `done` should be initialized to something that's not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to read and discard the rest of an invalid input line. Add e. g.

```
        scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
```

in the `else` block.

Comment: In general this pattern actually doesn't work , because `%[` fails and stops reading if it matched zero characters, so the newline would be left in the buffer in that case.  However since OP always starts reading the following line by discarding whitespace, it will work in this case. The general case could be handled by `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");`

Comment: This seems similar to ignoring blank space. Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm new to C) but couldn't you just change the scanf function to scanf (" %c") so that the scanner knows to ignore blank space? (I'm not sure if this is what you mean by your comment or not)

Comment: He means that my suggestion would not discard a sole `\n` left in the input buffer (which is correct, but cannot happen with your format string). The purpose of both patterns is not mainly ignoring blank space, but rather ignoring (discarding) the rest of the invalid input that is left in the buffer from the point where your `scanf()` stopped. Consider the input line `abcd1 2 3` - Your program's `scanf()` reads `a` in c1, `b` in c2, `c` in c3, then stops because `d` cannot be converted to an integer, returns 3 and leaves `d1 2 3` in the buffer; in the next pass of the loop it reads `d` in c1.